# Compiling Shader Variant (UNITY)

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, shader

I just want to ask if there's a way to skip the `Compiling Shader Variant` on the building process in Unity . I can't find any reference about it. 
So if there's someone who knows how to do it please help me.

Comment: Well you can remove the `Always included shaders` for every project and I think that will skip the `Compiling Shader Variant`.

Comment: I'm building a 2D game so does it affect my game if i skip that? @Hristo

Comment: Well yes it does. This means that Unity will not include its default shaders to your project, meaning if you are using some Materials that use the `Standard` shader for example, it will be missing (pink) when you build the game. Unless you have included them in the Resources folder.

Comment: @Hristo Okay thank you .